# PHP how to delete file on local machine

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying to read the PDF files in each child job and pull out the number of pages in each. My code works perfectly for the first file, but not for the second. My thinking is that the file is not being overwritten by the second PDF that's pulled in.

I am downloading the file to read it, so there's no need to keep it afterwards.

I tried putting in a check to unlink the file after use, but I get a permission denied error.

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->library('Awss3', null, 'S3');
$PdfTranscriptInfo = $CI->MJob->getDOCCSPdfTranscript($copy['jobid']);
$filename = $PdfTranscriptInfo['origfilename'];
$PdfFilename = 'uploads/' . $copy['jobid'] . '/' . $filename;
$localfilename = FCPATH . 'tmp/local.pdf';
$fileData = $CI->S3->readfile($PdfFilename, false, 'bucket');
require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdf.php';
require_once 'application/libraries/fpdi/fpdi.php';
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($localfilename);

if ($pageCount == $copy['pagecount']) {
    echo '<td>' . $copy['pagecount'] . '</td>';
} else {
    echo '<td style="background-color:red;">' . $copy['pagecount'] . '/' . $pageCount . '</td>';
}
if (file_exists($localfilename)) {
    unlink(FCPATH . 'tmp/local.pdf');
}
```

I am not getting any error messages, but the page count for the second file ($pageCount) is the same as the first file, so it's obviously not picking up the second PDF.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** FCPATH is C:\wamp64\www\companyname\

Comment: Can you share the value of `FCPATH` ?

Comment: Edited my post to include FCPATH.

Comment: If I were you, I will write `unlink($localfilename)` instead of combining the path again. Anyways, it's unrelated to your problem. Your problems are: 1. the file is still in use (you didn't close the file handle before deleting); 2. probably didn't display the PHP error (suggest to check PHP error log)

Comment: @Raptor, thank you. I will check the error log.

Comment: @Raptor, if I don't specifically open the file, why would I need to close it, or does it get opened indirectly by me calling the readfile command?

Comment: Just checked the official doc, the function `$fpdi->setSourceFile()` will open a file handle. You can use `$fpdi->cleanUp()` to close it. Docs: https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v1/the-fpdi-class/#index-3-5